# Visual Studio 2017 debugger closes select list

Tags: debugging, visual-studio-2017, internet-explorer-11

Wondering if anyone else out there is having this hair pulling issue with Visual Studio 2017.

I am working on an ASP.NET MVC and jquery application. I am seeing an odd behavior when I run the app in VS (hitting F5 key) the app runs and loads but every time I try and click on any select list (HTML Selects) they open and close very quickly making it impossible to choose a value. When that happens I noticed an HTML inspector tab opens in VS and closes rather quickly. This is driving me nuts because the only way I have found to remedy the issue is to launch the app in and debug in chrome.

Any ideas , is it IE or Visual Studio or both.

Comment: First you need to check that whether any event get fired when you try to click on select list which caused select list to get close quickly. Than you can try to create a new page and try to put a simple select list in it and try to run it to check whether it has the same behavior or not. For testing purpose, try to publish your app and try to open it in IE to check for the issue. If issue is not producible than possible that there some issue with Visual Studio. But still it is too early to decide without checking your application code. If issue persist than try to post your sample code.

Comment: It looks like an issue with Visual Studio when it tries to connect the DOM inspector! because when the application is published the problem does not exist it is only during debug. I still dont have a solution for the issues other then debug JS using Chrome!

Comment: Did you try to repair the Visual Studio? If not, You can try to do it to check whether it solves your issue or not.

Comment: Yep tried that, and still happens. The odd thing is it comes and goes sometimes its gone for days at a time.

Comment: Looks like some specific action triggering this issue. You can try to check for odd setting or any unusual thing may help to narrow down the issue.